# GCM send message faulty fonts

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm creating a JavaServer Faces project to send messages to my Android application as directed in https://github.com/google/gcm.

It works fine when I perform modal messaging in:

```
public static void main (String [] args) { sendMessage() }
```

But when I call the method to send messages from the web interface, the message appears in Android with faulty Vietnamese font.

Comment: It may be handy to have more of your code, E.G client code and server setup

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the requests send from the server as notification. It seems like they are are properly encoded with the correct parameters. Please make sure that the requests are UTF-8 encoded where spaces are replaced by + symbol.

The URL encoding has a % symbol or a character and a two-character hex value corresponding to a UTF-8 character. This may differ from language to language.

Change to content type to specify the charset=UTF-8 and then encode the request likewise. Follow the instruction on the GCM docs.

The HTTP header must contain the following headers:

```
Authorization: key=YOUR_API_KEY
Content-Type: application/json for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.
```